# ¿Cómo mostrar un texto con color de letra degradado usando CSS?

Tags: html, css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hola, alguien me podria ayudar como poner  con css el color de texto como el de la imagen ?

Comment: Como no, aqui veras algo parecido: https://codepen.io/chaczyk/pen/QWWjydZ

Comment: Necesitas proveer más información sobre el problema, por favor revisa las secciones de ayuda de la comunidad para saber cómo formular una buena pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

Espero te sirva

```css
h1 {
  background: #ccc;
  background: linear-gradient(yellow, pink,purple,blue,green);
  font-family: system-ui;
  font-size: 4rem;
  line-height: 115%;

  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<h1>The place where your <br>ideas come true</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

Podes lograrlo usando:

- Un fondo generado con [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient)
- Y al texto aplicandole [`mix-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode)

#### Ejemplo:

```css
.backdrop {
  background: linear-gradient(130deg, #d78943, #eb5956 25%, #5370e9, #5370e9, #27ae60 75%);
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: white;
  background: #000;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="backdrop">
  <div class="text">The place where your ideas come true</div>
</div>
```